# Como criar um background skew responsivo

Tags: css

Fiz um background **Skew** usando pseudo-elements porém a parte vermelha fica pra fora da margem da pagina, como ajuda pra ficar somente dentro da margem ?

```css
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
.content{
    background-color: chartreuse;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.content::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    transform: skew(-10deg);
    transform-origin: top;
}
.content::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: -60px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    transform-origin: top;
}
```

```html
    <div class="content">
        <h1>NADA</h1>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara o problema é o `right: -60px` que vc colocou no pseudo elemento

Para corrigir isso uma das opções é descontar `60px` do `width` e não jogar o elemento `60px` para fora da tela com um `right` negativo

Para isso use um `calc`, como o seu `width` é `30%` tire 60px dele, tipo assim:

`width: calc(30% - 60px);`

Veja o resultado no exemplo abaixo

```css
      *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
.content{
    background-color: chartreuse;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.content::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    transform: skew(-10deg);
    transform-origin: top;
}
.content::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: calc(30% - 60px);
    background-color: #ff0000;
    transform-origin: top;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <h1>NADA</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Vlw entendi, uma duvida acha que vale mais a pena usar imagens feita no photoshop pra criar esses backgrounds? ou css é o melhor?

Comment: @JavaScripto nessa caso em particular com certeza CSS, nem tenho dúvida quanto a isso... mesmo se vc quiser uma imagem dentro é só colocar como background image etc, não tem pq fazer nada no Photoshop nesse caso. Jovem se vc achar que a resposta resolveu o problema lembre-se de marca-la como aceita nesse ícone ✔︎, abaixo das setinhas ao lado da resposta, assim ela não fica em aberto mesmo tendo sido resolvida ;)

Comment: obg marquei, resolveu sim, to iniciando e tava cogitando a posibilidade de usar imagens pra fica meus backgrounds tipo skew, curvas, slantled.., obg boa tarde.

Comment: @JavaScripto valeu a força man